# Can some help me the list comprehension of the below for loop?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

> Create a list of all elements in the string “Yellow Yaks like yelling and yawning and #yesturday they yodled while eating yuky yams” by ignoring a,e,i,o,u in the element

I wrote the for loop:

```
mystring = "Yellow Yaks like yelling and yawning and yesterday they yodled while eating yuky yams"

newlist =[]
mylist=mystring.split()
for word in mylist:
    for letter in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
        if letter in word:
            word =word.replace(letter,'')
    newlist.append(word)
newlist
```

Output from the for loop:

```
['Yllw',
 'Yks',
 'lk',
 'yllng',
 'nd',
 'ywnng',
 'nd',
 'ystrdy',
 'thy',
 'ydld',
 'whl',
 'tng',
 'yky',
 'yms']
```

I tried the following for compressed for loop:

```
mylist=[word.replace(letter,'') for word in mystring.split() for letter in ['a','e','i','o','u'] if letter in word]
mylist
```

Output:

```
['Yllow',
 'Yellw',
 'Yks',
 'lik',
 'lke',
 'ylling',
 'yellng',
 'nd',
 'ywning',
 'yawnng',
 'nd',
 'yesterdy',
 'ystrday',
 'thy',
 'yodld',
 'ydled',
 'whil',
 'whle',
 'eting',
 'ating',
 'eatng',
 'yky',
 'yms']
```

I know the logic is incorrect but don't know how to fix it. Can you explain what needs to be done to fix it and why?

Answer (score 0):

```py
vowels = 'aeiou'
final_list = [word.translate(str.maketrans('', '', vowels)) for word in mystring.split()]
print(final_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**